# Which is the support library that I have to choose?

Tags: android-studio, android-support-library

My application has **minSdk** at 15 and **targetSdk** at 20. I need a support library because my application uses the *PageViewer* view.

Reading the documentation I read that the support library *vx* is designed to be used on the API level x. I think that the version's number x should be between 15 and 20.

How should I choose that number?

Secondly, using android studio I have to add the following line in a file named build.grandle, for using the support library *v4*.

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
```

What is the meaning of the suffix *20.0.0*?

Answer (score 0):

The support libraries have different revisions/versions. You can check more info [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)

Adding this part in your gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
```

you are telling gradle to get the *support-library-v4 with revision 20.0.0*.

About which version you should use. If you compiling with api20, you can use the revision 20.